# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in bot emulator

Tags: botframework

How to resolve **request to https://localhost:3978/api/messages failed, reason: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR** in bot emulator?

Comment: Try use `http://localhost:3978/api/messages`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in bot emulator

As I suggested in comment, to connect a bot running on local host, you can specify message endpoint in the emulator with `http://localhost:3978/api/messages`.

Besides, if you build your bot application using Bot Builder SDK for .NET in Visual Studio, to enable SSL and access site via https, you can set ***SSL Enabled*** option to ***True*** in project Properties window.

[image]

***Test result:***

[image]